Prove that the inf of the quotient functional are the same for all $\lambda $
Let $q: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, strictly positive and such that $\lim _{|x| \rightarrow \infty} q(x)=0$. For $\lambda \geq 0$ and $p \in\left(2,2^*\right)$, consider the problems
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-\Delta u+(1+\lambda q(x)) u=|u|^{p-2} u, \\
u \in H^1\left(\mathbb{R}^N\right) .
\end{array}\right.
$$
Weak solutions of these problems are, for example, critical points of the functionals $Q_\lambda: H^1\left(\mathbb{R}^N\right) \backslash\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
Q_\lambda(u)=\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla u|^2 d x+\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}(1+\lambda q(x)) u^2 d x}{\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u|^p d x\right)^{2 / p}} .
$$
now I want to Prove that for every $\lambda>0$,
$$
\inf _{u \in H^1\left(\mathbb{R}^N\right) \backslash\{0\}} Q_\lambda(u)=\inf _{u \in H^1\left(\mathbb{R}^N\right) \backslash\{0\}} Q_0(u) .
$$, here is my attempt, I want to first multiply the equation by $u$ and get the relation between $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla u|^2 d x+\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}(1+\lambda q(x)) u^2 d x$ and $\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|u|^p d x\right)^{2 / p}$ because the minimizer may be the weak solution of the equation, but they can't cancel each out, now I don't know what to do

maybe we can let a sequence that the integral is almost 0 on a bounded region, and concentrate on a reagion that tend to infinity, hence q tends to 0 at that region
